# Build VB.NET string from array of Integers

Tags: string, vb.net, unicode

I need to construct a string from Unicode values found in a `.csv` file. I have used Python to extract the integer values and I need to rebuild the string in VB.NET to check for the presence of the string with a file parser.
I've tried using both the `Chr` and `ChrW` functions but both give me errors when I hit the `8315` value.

```
Public Function FromAsciiArray(AsciiArray As Integer()) As String

    Dim strOut As String = ""

    For Each asciiValue In AsciiArray
        strOut += ChrW(asciiValue)
    Next
    Return strOut

End Function

Dim strVECTOR = FromAsciiArray(
    New Integer() {86, 69, 67, 84, 79, 82, 32, 40, 109, 109, 47, 115, 8315, 185, 41}
)
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If you have Unicode characters, why does your method have "Ascii" in the name?

Comment: It's legacy from when I was using it for non unicode. I'll change it if someone can work out the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
Dim arr = New Integer() {86, 69, 67, 84, 79, 82, 32, 40, 109, 109, 47, 115, 8315, 185, 41}
Dim str = String.Concat(arr.Select(Function(n) Convert.ToChar(n)))
Console.WriteLine(str)
```

Comment: Saved this as an example of the Predicate thingy. But when I ran it I got some VECTOR mm/ something had to take it apart to figure it out. Boy, that sure came by freight! Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function FromIntegers(CharacterValues As IEnumerable(Of Integer)) As String
    Return New String(CharacterValues.Select(Function(c) Convert.ToChar(c)).ToArray())    
End Function
```

This will work with Arrays, Lists, and other integer sequences (thus removing "Array" from the name, and fixing the "ASCII" while we're at it). You can call it just like you did in the question:

```
Dim VECTOR As String = FromIntegers(
    New Integer() {86, 69, 67, 84, 79, 82, 32, 40, 109, 109, 47, 115, 8315, 185, 41}
)
```

... where I made the slight adjustment that modern code tends to declare the type of the variable with the definition instead of with a name prefix.

If you really want to have fun, you can also do this:

```
Public Function FromIntegers(ParamArray CharacterValues() As Integer) As String
    Return New String(CharacterValues.Select(Function(c) Convert.ToChar(c)).ToArray())    
End Function
```

which will let you call the function like just like you did in the question:

```
Dim VECTOR As String = FromIntegers(
    New Integer() {86, 69, 67, 84, 79, 82, 32, 40, 109, 109, 47, 115, 8315, 185, 41}
)
```

And also call it like this:

```
Dim VECTOR As String = FromIntegers(86, 69, 67, 84, 79, 82, 32, 40, 109, 109, 47, 115, 8315, 185, 41)
```

Finally, if you're sure of the character encoding and depending on how the Python side handles things or how you parse the csv data, we might be able to do a little better still via the [System.Text.Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) family of classes.